# Bitmap.getPixel crashes program

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, crash, collision-detection

I was working on bitmap collisions in Android Studio (detecting when the two images actually collide, not just the two rects) and I wrote the following method. The first part of the code-all of the if statements- are to determine the position of the two intersecting rectangles and to create a rectangle that is made up of the overlap between the intersecting rectangles. The second part of the code tries to iterate through each pixel in newly created rectangle and determine whether it is transparent or not. However, in order to do this, I use pic1.getPixel (pic1 and pic2 are my two bitmaps with valid images in them) but the program crashes every time I try to use getPixel. Also I checked to make sure that the first part of the code works correctly and it does. Why is this happening?

```
 public Boolean isCollision(Rect r1, Rect r2 )
{
    if(r1.intersect(r2))
    {
        Rect r3 = new Rect(0,0,0,0);
        if (r2.left < r1.right && r2.top < r1.bottom && r2.right > r1.right && r2.bottom > r1.bottom)
        {
            r3.set(r2.left, r2.top, r1.right, r1.bottom);
        }
        else if (r2.right > r1.left && r2.top < r1.bottom && r2.left < r1.left && r2.bottom > r1.bottom)
        {
            r3.set(r1.left, r2.top, r2.right, r1.bottom);
        }
        else if (r2.left < r1.right && r2.bottom > r1.top)
        {
            r3.set(r2.left, r1.top, r1.right, r2.bottom);
        }
        else if(r2.right > r1.left && r2.bottom > r1.top)
        {
            r3.set(r1.left, r1.top, r2.right, r2.bottom);
        }
        Log.v("Debugging", "Made it part the overlapping rectangle creation");
        for (int i = r3.left; i<r3.right; i++)
        {
            for (int j = r3.top; j < r3.bottom; j++)
            {

                /*Log.v("Debugging","Pixel 1: " + Integer.toString(pic1.getPixel(i,j)));
                Log.v("Debugging","Pixel 2: " + Integer.toString(pic2.getPixel(i,j)));
                Log.v("Debugging","Transparent color: " + Integer.toString(Color.TRANSPARENT));*/
                if (pic1.getPixel(i,j) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                {
                    if (pic2.getPixel(i,j) != Color.TRANSPARENT)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v("Debugging", "Made it past the pixel search");
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: was the exception thrown by any chance an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: I don't think so. To my knowledge android studio would have told me if it threw an IndexOutofBoundsException but in my code it just goes into the runTimeinIt.java and goes straight to bringing up the crash dialog when I step through my code

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, turns out for the x and y values, I was using the position of the pixel based on the coordinate system of the screen. However, for getPixel, the 0,0 point is in the upper right hand corner of the image that you are trying to get pixels for. Therefore,the problem was solved when I did getPixel(i-rect.left,j-rect.top)